# Pyinstaller with tkinter and a custom folder

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I'm struggling to figure this out. I have a little python script with a GUI that uses Tkinter. This script needs to access a folder to save and view images. This works when using the script and running from the commandline. However I'd like to build this as a single file app with pyinstaller. While the build works and the GUI works, saving and viewing images from the folder doesn't work. The script is designed to look for the folder in a directory down from the script:

```
APP_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))    
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(APP_FOLDER+'/backgrounds'):
    for file in files:
        if not file.startswith('.'):
            action_with_arg = partial(setBG, APP_FOLDER+'/backgrounds/'+file)
            BGArray.append(APP_FOLDER+'/backgrounds/'+file)
            img = Image.open(APP_FOLDER+'/backgrounds/'+file)
            img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]/10),int(img.size[1]/10)))
            img1 =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            button = ttk.Button(frameBG.scrollable_frame,image=img1,command=action_with_arg)
            button.image = img1
            button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to be able to open an image from a folder with your app? sth like a default app for opening files with say `.png` extension?

Comment: There are two possible problems I would suspect. One is making sure the image files got included in the pyinstaller build. The other is making sure the path to them will be the same relative to whatever `__file__` comes out as. To debug maybe you should have some print statements of what `__file__` is when packaged and also just list out the files under `os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: Correct. I want to open and display an image in my app - even copy the image to a backgrounds folder inside my app.

Comment: I can verify that the `__file__` is in my scripts directory and it works well when I run the python script from terminal. However when I make the app with pyinstaller, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `sys.executable` might work instead of `__file__`, I am not sure. Remember having similar issue many years ago, and can't remember how I resolved it, but I had found `__file__` didn't work.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire - You pointed me in the right direction. Its not sys.executable, its sys._MEIPASS. That works and seems to have solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the executable where the source code used to be? When pyinstaller complies, it puts everything in a subfolder--cutting access to anything outside of the folder and stopping you from accessing your images.

If this is the case, then you just need to move the executable back to the original folder location of the source code.